# Swift - Toggling CollectionView cells to toggle items in an Array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two CollectionView's. One CollectionView (allHobbiesCV) is pre-populated with Hobbies you can select. The other CollectionView (myHobbiesCV) is empty, but if you tap on a hobby in the allHobbiesCV, it gets added to the myHobbiesCV. This is all working great.

I would like the tapped allHobbiesCV cells to switch to selected, it adds the hobby to myHobbiesCV, then if the user taps the same selected cell again in the allHobbiesCV, it removes that hobby from the myHobbiesCV. Basically a toggle add/remove.

*Two things to note:*

1. Users can manually select hobbies in myHobbiesCV, then tap a [Remove Hobby] button.
2. Hobbies will be sorted by seasons, so there will be 4 different data sets (Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn) for allHobbiesArray. Depending on which season (ViewController) the user taps. They can select as many / few cells from each as they like.

**Problem:**

I'm crashing on any toggle besides the first cell. If I select the first cell in allHobbiesCV, I can select it again, and it will remove it from the myHobbiesCV. If I select that same cell again (to toggle it,) I crash. If I select any other cell besides the first, I crash.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 7 from section 0 which only contains 3 items before the update'
```

**Class Level**

```
// Winter Hobbies
let allHobbiesArray = ["Skiing", "Snowboarding", "Drinking Bourbon", "Snow Shoeing", "Snowmobiling", "Sledding", "Shoveling Snow", "Ice Skating"]
var myHobbiesArray = [String]()
var allSelected = [IndexPath]()
var didSelectIPArray = [IndexPath]()
```

**Data Source**

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ALL", for: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
        cell.allHobbiesLabel.text = allHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]

        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
        else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }

        return cell
    }

    else {
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MY", for: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.myHobbiesLabel.text = myHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]

        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }


        return cell
    }


}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        return allHobbiesArray.count
    }
    else {
        return myHobbiesArray.count
    }

}

}
```

**Delegate**

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        if myHobbiesArray.count <= 6
            self.allSelected = []

            didSelectIPArray.append(indexPath) // Store the selected indexPath in didSelectIPArray

            myHobbiesArray.insert(allHobbiesArray[indexPath.item], at: 0)
            let allHobbiesCell = allHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
            allHobbiesCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

            // Store all of the selected cells in an array
            didSelectIPArray.append(indexPath) 

            myHobbiesCV.reloadData()
        }
    }


    else {
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        allSelected = self.myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
    }


}

// Deselecting selected cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {

        // Yellow is the unselected cell color. So let's change it back to yellow.
        let allHobbiesCell = allHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
        allHobbiesCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        // Remove (toggle) the cells. This is where I am stuck/crashing.
        let indices = didSelectIPArray.map{ $0.item }
        myHobbiesArray = myHobbiesArray.enumerated().flatMap { indices.contains($0.0) ? nil : $0.1 }
        self.myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: didSelectIPArray)

        myHobbiesCV.reloadData()

        didSelectIPArray.remove(at: indexPath.item) // Remove the deselected indexPath from didSelectIPArray
    }

    else { // MyHobbies CV
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        // Store the selected cells to be manually deleted.
        allSelected = self.myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems!

    }
}
}
```

**Delete Button**

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for item in didSelectIPArray {
        self.allHobbiesCV.deselectItem(at: item, animated: false) // Try deselecting the deleted items in allHobbiesCV... This is crashing.
    }
}
```

The issue is how I am trying to toggle the allHobbiesCV cells in didDeselect. Was my approach correct in saving the selected cells in didSelectIPArray?

I'll be happy to provide further insight if needed. Thank you much in advance friends!

Comment: I wouldn't store the index in the `myHobbiesArray`; store the hobby name.  Then when you want to delete something, just use `myHobbiesArray.index(of:hobbyName)` to work out which index you need

Comment: @Paulw11 - myHobbiesArray is just storing all of my selected hobbies, in case I want to manually delete any. Did you mean "didSelectIPArray" - which is where I am trying to store the selected index path of the selected (toggled) cells?

Comment: Right yes, There is no need for any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for all of that `map` and `flatmap` stuff.  You can simply remove the object from the selected hobbies array:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        if myHobbiesArray.count <= 6
            self.allSelected = []
            myHobbiesArray.insert(allHobbiesArray[indexPath.item], at: 0)

            let allHobbiesCell = allHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
            allHobbiesCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

            myHobbiesCV.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)])
        }
    } else {
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        allSelected = self.myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {

        // Yellow is the unselected cell color. So let's change it back to yellow.
        let allHobbiesCell = allHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
        allHobbiesCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        let hobby = allHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]

        if let index = myHobbiesArray.index(of:hobby) {
             myHobbiesArray.remove(at: index)
             myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section:0)])
        }
    } else { // MyHobbies CV
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        // Store the selected cells to be manually deleted.
        allSelected = self.myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems!

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow @Paulw11 - this is wonderful! No more crashing, and the toggling works great!! Just a quick question. How would I DESELECT allHobbiesCV cells if they've been deleted below manually by selecting and then tapping Delete? That should answer my other question of how do I keep the cells SELECTED once the user dismisses the VC and then segues back to it (because right now, all the cells are deselected). Store all selected hobbies, then on viewWillAppear load the selection, and then unselect if same index has been deleted?

Comment: I've updated my code to include my attempt here. I'm trying to save the selected index in didSelectIPArray. (didSelectIPArray.append(indexPath) in didSelectItemAt) // Then I try removing it in didDeselect (didSelectIPArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)) // Then finally, when I manually select a cell from myHobbies to delete it, it should deselect the selected cells from allHobbies in my button action. It's crashing on allHobbies deselect, and the delete button does not deselect anything. Any help is appreciated Paul.

Comment: I've posted this as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099851/using-a-button-to-deselect-cells-in-a-collectionview - would love it if you and your 35-some years of programming experience can help me out :)