# Using a button to deselect cells in a collectionview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have two collection views. Tapping unselected cells in Collection View 1 selects them, and adds the selected cell to Collection View 2. Tapping on selected cells in Collection View 1 (allHobbiesCV) will unselect them and remove them from Collection View 2 (myHobbiesCV). Essentially, all it's doing is toggling.

Cells in Collection View 2 can also be manually removed by selecting as few or many as desired, then pressing a 'Remove' button. This process works great, except the cells in Collection View 1 still remain selected, even if that particular cell was removed from Collection View 2.

**How do I use the remove button to deselect cells from Collection View 1 if they were manually selected and removed from Collection View 2?**

*Class level -*

```
var allHobbiesArray = [String]()
var allHobbiesArraySelected = [String]()

var myHobbiesArray = [String]()
var myHobbiesArraySelected = [String]()
```

**didSelectItemAt**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    // All Hobbies
    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        let item = allHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]
        let cell = allHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell

        if let itemIndex = allHobbiesArraySelected.index(of:item) {
            // DID DESELECT
            allHobbiesArraySelected.remove(at:itemIndex)
            myHobbiesArray.remove(at: itemIndex)
            myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: itemIndex, section:0)])
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        }
        else {
            // DID SELECT
            allHobbiesArraySelected.insert(item, at: 0)
            myHobbiesArray.insert(item, at: 0)
            myHobbiesCV.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section:0)])
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }

        allHobbiesCV.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)

        for cell in myHobbiesCV.visibleCells {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
        myHobbiesArraySelected.removeAll()
        //myHobbiesCV.reloadData() // needed?
    }

    // My Hobbies
    else {
        let item = myHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell

        if let itemIndex = myHobbiesArraySelected.index(of:item) {
            // DID DESELECT
            myHobbiesArraySelected.remove(at: itemIndex)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
        else {
            // DID SELECT
            myHobbiesArraySelected.insert(item, at: 0)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        myHobbiesCV.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**cellForItem**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ALL", for: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
        cell.allHobbiesCellLabel.text = allHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]

        let allHobbies = allHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]
        if allHobbiesArraySelected.index(of: allHobbies) != nil {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
        else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        }

        return cell
    }

    else { // myHobbiesCV
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MY", for: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.myHobbiesCellLabel.text = myHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]

        let myHobbies = myHobbiesArray[indexPath.item]
        if myHobbiesArraySelected.index(of: myHobbies) != nil {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }


        return cell
    }

}
```

**numberOfItemsInSection**

```
    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        return allHobbiesArray.count
    }
    else {
        return myHobbiesArray.count
    }
```

**Delete button**

```
@IBAction func deleteHobbyButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("all Hobbies - \(allHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems!)")

    if let selectedItemPaths = myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems {

        var allItemIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        var tempSelectedItems = Array(allHobbiesArraySelected) // Need to use a temporary copy otherwise the element indexes will change
        for itemPath in selectedItemPaths {

            let removeItem = allHobbiesArraySelected[itemPath.item]
            if let removeIndex = tempSelectedItems.index(of: removeItem) {
                print("if let removeIndex")
                tempSelectedItems.remove(at: removeIndex)
            }

            if let allItemsIndex = allHobbiesArray.index(of: removeItem) {
                print("if let allItemsIndex")
                allItemIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: allItemsIndex, section: 0))
            }
        }

        allHobbiesArraySelected = tempSelectedItems // Selected items array without the removed items
        myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at:selectedItemPaths)
        myHobbiesCV.reloadData()
        allHobbiesCV.reloadItems(at: allItemIndexPaths)  // Reload to update the selected status
    }

}
```

The problem now is nothing is evaluating in the remove button. That first print statement always returns an empty array. And nothing prints in the if let check. Is there a way to use myHobbiesArraySelected instead of indexPathsForSelectedItems? (Since I'm saving the selected items in an array now) Along with the original intended functionality of deselecting the cell in allHobbiesCV if it was manually deleted in myHobbiesCV.

Thanks friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to store selected index paths, as these are coupled to the collection view.  If you store the selected *items* then you can always determine the appropriate index path, using the item's index in the array. You can also determine an item quickly from a given index path.

In the code below I have used the type `Item` for your underlying item, but it could be `String` or `Int` or any object type.  If you use your own class or struct, ensure you make it conform to `Equatable` and `Hashable`.

```
var allItems:[Item]
var selectedItems[Item]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == allItemsCV {
        let item = allItems[IndexPath.row]
        if let itemIndex = selectedItems.index(of:item) {
            selectedItems.remove(at:itemIndex)
            selectedItemsCV.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: itemIndex, section:0)])
        } else {
            selectedItems.insert(item, at: 0)
            selectedItemsCV.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section:0)])
        }
        allItemsCV.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       // cell for item at indexPath needs to render the selected/deselected 
          state correctly based on the item being in the selectedItems array

        allItemsCV.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

    }
}

@IBAction func removeButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
//...
    if let selectedItemPaths = selectedItemCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        var allItemIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        var tempSelectedItems = Array(selectedItems) // Need to use a temporary copy otherwise the element indexes will change
        for itemPath in selectedItemPaths {
            let removeItem = selectedItems[itemPath.item]
            if let removeIndex = tempSelectedItems.index(of: removeItem) {
                tempSelectedItems.remove(at: removeItem)
            }
            if let allItemsIndex = allItems.index(of: removeItem) {
                allItemIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: allItemsIndex, section: 0))
            }
        }
        selectedItems = tempSelectedItems // Selected items array without the removed items
        selectedItemsCV.deleteItems(at:selectedItemPaths)
        allItemsCV.reloadItems(at: allItemIndexPaths)  // Reload to update the selected status
    }
}
```

Comment: Spent the better part of the last hour and a half studying your code. I'm caught up on allItems / selectedItems. I want these to be Int, instead of Item, so that I can get the correct index path, yes? I've updated my code in the original post. Crashing on didSelectItemAt (fatal error: Index out of range). would allItems actually be my data source? (Which is just an array of strings to fill in the cells)

Comment: No, don't store indexpaths: they will change as you insert/remove items. Store the actual item and find it in the array when you need to.

Comment: okay i fixed my code a bit more. Not storing the indexpath now; storing the item. the cell selection / deselection is working (albeit odd visual issues of the selected state sliding in.) I think I can resolve those... but the crash is happening on deleteButtonPressed.  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0. ***. Am I stepping in the correct direction here?

Comment: Additionally, there doesn't need to be any logic with in didDeselect anymore, correct? (besides the visual changes)

Comment: Yes.  That means that there was a mismatch between the number of items in returned by `numberOfItemsInSection` and the number of items that the collection view *thinks* should be there; e.g. If there were 3 and you delete 1 then there should be 2.  If `numberOfItems` returns a different number then you get that exception

Comment: Correct.  You can use select/deselect rather than the single selection method I showed; you would just split the `if` statement in `didSelect` so that the first bit is in `didDeselect` and the `else` stays in `didSelect`

Comment: i think i'm at the finish line. Updated my code for numberOfItems & remove button. My crash is happening because of myHobbiesArray.count, but i don't know where to update that in removeButtonPressed. Do I update the actual array? or just update the count of items in myHobbiesArray?   (your patience and assistance has been greatly appreciated. can't wait to mark this as resolved! thanks paul)

Comment: Why doesn't  cell.isSelected in cellForItemAt work with your solution? If I scroll the selected cell out of view, then back, the selected visual state does not persist.

Comment: Because cells are reused, so tracking state in the cell object won't work. You must track selection state in some other structure; such as a set of IndexPaths or by comparing against the selected indexes of the collectionview

Comment: I scrapped my entire xcode project and started from scratch. I'm now incorporating your method of saving the items in arrays! I have two arrays for each CV; all & selected. I have just about ALL of it working (including pushing the selected states and cells to multiple views! yay!) The last hurdle is the remove button... I can't get the code inside of it to evaluate. Instead of using an indexPath (which i WAS doing..) I want to just use the new arrays I have. Code has been updated. Can you take a peek at it and provide some guidance on getting that remove btn working? THANK YOU PAUL

Answer (score 0):

***Update:*** IndexPath conforms `Equatable` (see comment from @Paulw11)
<s>you compare the objects `IndexPath` in `contains` but but even if an instance of `indexPath` path have the same sections and rows the object itself is different.</s>

<s>1. solution: compare values
change the contains to to compare the sections and rows</s>

2. solution: stick on item id
   stick on an unique item id which you store in the array. then you are on the more save situation, if collection1 and collection2 has different sizes and sections

i would suggest to implement solution 2

Comment: #2 sounds like a plan. how would you go about associating a unique id to an array element?

Comment: @muescha, `NSIndexPath` conforms to `Equatable` and `Hashable`. This ensures that operations, such as `contains` will work correctly;  contains doesn't just compare object references, it compares the index path values via the `Equatable` protocol such that two "different" IndexPaths with the same section and row are equal.